# How to set constants in module by function and use it in another function in python?

Tags: python, function, constants

I want to get in print `A2`. What is the best way to do that?
(for any numbers and types of constants):

```
VAR1=1
VAR2=2

def choose_var(variation):
    if variation == 1:
        VAR1 = "A"
        VAR2 = 2
    elif variation ==2:
        VAR1 = "B"
        VAR2 = 3 
        
def get_some_stuff():
    return str(VAR1 + VAR2)
    
choose_var(1)
print(get_some_stuff())
```

without passing `VAR1` and `VAR2` to `get_some_stuff()`

Comment: Accepting that your immediate code problem has been answered by @azro - Global variables usually can be and are best avoided. In this case simply use `choose_var` to return values and pick these up in `get_some_stuff`. As code gets longer and more complex, such globals make testing and debugging difficult.

Comment: You are right, global variables is BAD PRACTICE, but when code work many years and created only for my purpose and makes a couple little things then is not necessary make FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make both variables `global`, by default they're local to the method

```
def choose_var(variation):
    global VAR1, VAR2
    if variation == 1:
        VAR1 = "A"
        VAR2 = 2
    elif variation == 2:
        VAR1 = "B"
        VAR2 = 3
```

And fix the concatenation between int and str

```
def get_some_stuff():
    return f"{VAR1}{VAR2}"
```